# Default sort order for elasticsearch without a query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm just wondering what the default sort order for elasticsearch is when you just do an all search without any query. I think the documents state that a search will be done by relevance score but on a full search all scores are set to 1.

Yet when I refresh my results the almost always stay in the same order. I'm guessing something else is also managing the sort then?

Does anybody know what else is sorting the default results?

Comment: were you able to figure out the answer?

Comment: @AmitTripathi No I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I have not been working with Elasticsearch for a while, so if somebody were to still answer this I would love to save this as a future reference.

Comment: I think they're returned in the order that they were added to ES.